# Object to string conversion error

Tags: 8, nodes

When I try to make a new Basic Page, I get the error below:

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType could not be converted to string in Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getClass() (line 72 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Html.php).

I am currently on 8.3.7, but I get the same error when upgrading to 8.4.2 as well. This happens for creating all content types. Has anyone else come across this? I am a little worried since it is a core issue, but I assume it is some kind of configuration issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Someone's passing `$node_type` instead of `$node_type->id()`. Look for calls to `Html::getClass` in custom code and you'll probably find it

Comment: ... if not, then enable full error messages with backtrace and you'll see.

Comment: No calls to Html::getClass in custom code at all. The template being rendered is core/themes/classy/templates/layout/html.html.twig. So it doesn't seem to be my code, but then again, it has to be lol.

Comment: Look also for the Twig filter `|clean_class`, this is an alias for the php method. Do you have an error message with a backtrace? This should show you what to look for.

Comment: Ya looks like that is all over. I will look into it deeper. Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: All right, so if I add a @ in front of the (string) cast in Html:getClass, then it renders fine. This makes sense given the error.

Secondly, if I add a __toString() function to the NodeType class, then it works as well. Again, going along with the error.

Here is a bit of my quandary now though. We have not made any changes to the Seven theme, which is the only time this error is coming up. We have not extended it or made any templates at all, so I am not sure how this is happening.

I attempted removing all the |clean_class calls in our templates, but to no avail.

Comment: Trying again (3rd time now), did you switch to full error messages with backtrace (/admin/config/development/logging)? This should help a lot in finding the code which calls Html::getClass().

Comment: This is what I get.

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType could not be converted to string in Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getClass() (line 72 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Html.php).

Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getClass(Object) (Line: 46)
__TwigTemplate_be8c7bbb9c824f2826368d7c8da984c6279779db72a67fd8056a00bb23b816f2->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 432)
Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 403)

Comment: The rest:

Twig_Template->display(Array) (Line: 411)
Twig_Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
twig_render_template('core/themes/classy/templates/layout/html.html.twig', Array) (Line: 384)

Comment: Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Great, you have now two templates, one compiled and one source. Don't know if they are for the same template, but they probably are. If you open both you can easily see this. Hope you'll find now the code causing the error in this template.